# Automator: Service to list File Paths of selected items, into Text File

Tags: finder, automator, path

How can this Automator Service for Finder be created?

- I'd like to be able to use Finder's Context menu (by right-clicking a Finder item) to run a Service that gets the file paths of the selected files.
- The paths should be entered into a Text File (which can be unsaved or saved in the current folder).

Furthermore:

- I *currently* only need to be able to get the paths of *multiple selected files* – but not the paths of subfolder contents, etc. I hope that serves not to overcomplicate things.
- I would prefer if the filenames don't have Escaping Spaces (`"Like\ This"`), but instead normal spaces – but if there's a setting for that, I'd like how to alter between the modes within the script.

Comment: You can get the pathnames in Finder after selecting the items, right-click and then press the option key. Copy n Items changes to: Copy n Items as Pathnames

Comment: @user3439894 Wow, had no idea, thanks! I guess I can't accept it as an answer, as it's the right answer to the wrong question. But this is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for something that's more "pure Automator," here's one option (although, as was mentioned in the comments, right-clicking on the items in Finder, holding <kbd>option</kbd>, and selecting `Copy Items as Pathnames` is probably the easiest solution):

- Accepts `files or folders` in `Finder`
- Set Value of Variable `Inputs`
- Run Shell Script: `/usr/bin/dirname "$1"` (make sure to pass input `as arguments`)
- Set Value of Variable `Parent Folder`
- Get Value of Variable `Inputs` <-- this should *not* accept input (right-click on the action and select `Ignore Input`)
- New Text File (`Plain text`, [whatever file name you want], `Parent Folder` (drag this in from the variables list))

I've included a screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of Service]

Comment: +1 Like use of pure Automator. I myself am not too good at pure Automator

Answer (score 3):

No script is needed, as this is already built into Finder (this works for one or multiple files):

- Right click on the file(s) in Finder
- Press and hold <kbd>option</kbd>
- Select `Copy [file name] as Pathname` (or `Copy [#] Items as Pathnames` for multiple files) in the context menu
- The pathnames are now saved to your clipboard. You can paste them into Notes or a text file

Comment: Plus one- trivial hand work that does not need scripting

Comment: -1 The OP is new to Automator. Providing a scripting alternative would allow them to learn. This solution while correct, does not answer the OPs question entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know how to create save and use a service menu item...

[image: ![enter image description here]

### Script

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set myExport to ""
    repeat with x in input
        set myExport to myExport & the POSIX path of x & return
    end repeat
    tell application "Finder" to set myPath to (POSIX path of (get (container of (first item of input)) as text))
    do shell script "echo " & the quoted form of myExport & " > " & the quoted form of (myPath & "/file_list.txt")
end run
```

Comment: @user3439894 Finder sends the files to input

Comment: @user3439894 Oh I see now. Yes that's correct.

Comment: Change the second-to-last line to `tell application "Finder" to set myPath to (POSIX path of (get (container of (first item of input)) as text))` and the last line to `do shell script "echo " & the quoted form of myExport & " > " & the quoted form of (myPath & "/file_list.txt")` and it'll work if the first item isn't a directory. N.B.: There's probably a cleaner way to accomplish this.

Comment: @user3439894  can't fix now on mobile will fix later

Comment: @user3439894 Fixed :)

Comment: @JBis, you can delete the comments to me, as they are no longer needed.